# Why were terminal train stations built in Germany?

Tags: germany, political-history, imperial-germany, railroads, prussia

I talked to a friend who mentioned reading a theory about the placement of terminal vs passthrough train stations in Germany.

In this theory, the Prussians were responsible for this decision during the Second Reich. If a city was considered "friendly", it got a pass-through station. If the Prussians disliked a city for some reason, they made a terminal train station there, hoping to diminish its chances of becoming an important railway junction and thus subtly depriving it of economical and political importance.

According to this theory, later train stations were mostly built as pass-through stations, because nobody used the building of terminal stations as a political instrument.

Is there any support for this theory? Is it widely known among historians, or just idle musings of some popular science writer? If it is known, is there support for it, and how solid is it? What alternative theories exist for terminal stations?

---

Explanation of terms: A terminal station is where trains end, they cannot pass through it. The tracks enter the station building and end there. A pass-through station is one which has the tracks beside the building, and trains enter from the one side and continue on the other.

Comment: I would think that any "terminal" station can be converted in "non-terminal" just by adding a switchyard in the outsides of the city. Also, the theory of "friendly" and "unfriendly" cities inside your own country is quite curious.

Comment: @SJuan76 The Second Reich was an empire, not a country. Also, a switch yard solution will significantly decrease the overall travelling time of trains, especially in the times of steam locomotives. If I were a railway company manager, I would certainly route less trains through cities with a switching yard + terminal station combination.

Comment: Excluding the few colonies, it did not rule over non-German territory (unless you exclude Alsace & Lorraine) and all of it had voting rights. Also, what decreases the travelling time of trains is the stopping at the stations. Having to turn the locomotive around just takes some extra time, but not so much to make the switchyard solution much of an issue. Think also that making a passtrhough station involves a significant cost by buying city (expensive) terrain. Finally, do you have some *example* so we can say "yes, this city was despised by the government" or "the kaiser loved that city"?

Comment: Note that even a cursory search at the wikipedia explains that, during the second German Empire, there were a number of different railways companies. And while it explains that they were progressively in the hands of the state, it does not meant "the German Empire" but the regional states (like Baviera, Saxony, Baden, etc.). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transport_in_Germany#Epoch_I_.281871-1919.29

Comment: Not only Germany has terminal train stations. See the Wikipedia entry on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_station#Terminus

Comment: Seems like your friend was reading wild conjectures by random anonymous posters on 4chan's /pol/ or some such forum. Not only is the half-cocked idea of building terminal stations to punish cities ridiculous (**why even build any station there if you don't want the city to develop?**), the motivation of cutting off your own nose to spite your face is is juvenile. And yes, Imperial Germany was a country that styled itself an empire.

Comment: Can your friend also explain the train stations of Paris and London?

Comment: To clarify: while I am not convinced that the theory is correct, I don't think that objections of the kind "there shouldn't be unfriendly cities within a country" or "there are terminal stations in other places" are sufficient to address the question. The theory was in a book written by somebody with knowledge on the subject, not on 4chan, and presumably better presented than my third-hand account. Also we cannot assume perfect rationality in the Prussians or any other historical entity. What I am asking here is for recorded reasons for the building of terminal stations, (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) in the Second Reich territory, be they consistent with the theory or not. Saying "it would have been dumb of the Prussians to do that" or arguing on the precise definition of an empire is not particularly enlightening.

Comment: @rumtscho: These objections are indeed not very "hard", but then, the premise of the claim is questionable in the first place. The main stations of Munich and Frankfurt, for instance, are traffic hubs, and both are terminal stations. Especially before push-pull trains were a thing, terminal stations were where trains started and ended, or at least had to have considerable breaks, and to some extent, this is still the case nowadays. Consequently, this is were passengers are likely to get out and/or change trains - i.e., an important railway junction.

Comment: @SJuan76: 'any "terminal" station can be converted in "non-terminal"' - if you define "terminal" station that widely, I think there are no major terminal stations in Germany. Quite some large main stations are terminal stations in that trains can enter and leave the platform area only on one side (and therefore have to switch their direction before travelling further), but I think almost all, or all of these stations are connected to tracks that branch into various directions in front of the station/city.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace "Pass through" means there are rails going into the station and out of it, the station building is "beside" the  tracks. "Terminal" means the trains go into the building and cannot get out on the other side, the tracks end there.

Comment: Having a lot of terminal train station is a natural (early) state of building networks or roads or railroads. Also many (most?) central stations are actually terminal stations by your definition.

Answer (score 7):

Your friend should look up "[Anhalter Bahnhof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Anhalter_Bahnhof)", the grand terminus in Berlin. Berlin was at the time the capital of the German "Reich", and the idea the Kaiser would want to punish his own capital is a bit ludicrous. In fact the Anhalter Bahnhof, hailed as the "Gate to the South", was magnificent beyond compare and was used by Emporer Wilhelm II. for state receptions. Unfortunaltely very little is left (but should you ever come to Berlin, the Museum of Technology has a wonderful model of how Anhalter Bahnhof used to look like).

The German Wikipedia article on "[Kopfbahnhöfe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopfbahnhof)" suggests that they were build that way to emphasize the role of the city center (passengers could not simply pass through), which is more or less the opposite of what your friend claims.

Answer (score 6):

Terminal train stations were built in continental Europe because many railroads connected only two cities in the early to mid 19th century. There were not many rail lines, and the stations built were terminal stations. As the railroad network increased, the terminal stations could not be converted to passthrough anymore.

Comment: You also have to factor in the myriad of other Transportation options...the most important of which is walking. I question the premise that a "Terminal" is bad for a City's economy. Certianly not true of Grand Central Terminal in Manhattan.

Answer (score 4):

This is completely nonsense.

1. As @jjack mentioned in his answer in the mid 19th century the rail road net wasn't as large as today and connected few important cities, only.
   The advantage of such a terminal station was also that you can build it closer to the city.
   [Terminal station](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopfbahnhof) today's disadvantage wasn't present in the past because of the usage of steam trains which must be replaced often.
   See:
2. [Here is a plan of the Stuttgart terminal station from 1863](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuttgart_Hauptbahnhof#/media/File:Planskizze_alter_Bahnhof_Stuttgart_1863.jpg)

[In 1863 the Kingdom of Württemberg (with Stuttgart as capital city) was an independent kingdom (within the 'German Bund')](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Deutscher_Bund.png)

You can see that the plan for the station exists before Prussia had the influence within the HRE to manipulate the states within the HRE. Prussia had not this supremacy before the battle of Königgrätz in 1866 against Austria which let to the "Lesser German solution" afterwards (Bismarcks plan to form a German state with Prussia as leadership and without Austria). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Question

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Because the plan exists before prussia had the influence within the HRE to manipulate the states within the HRE. Prussia had not this supremacy before the battle of Königgrätz in 1866 against Austria which let to the "Lesser German solution" afterwards (Bismarcks plan to form a German state with prussia as leadership and without Austria). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Question

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: done

Answer (score 4):

The Imperial German rail network, in the late 19 Century, was largely designed and financed to facilitate military mobilization. THus any *terminal* stations would have been designed as *arrival* stations for debarking troops, first in South Saxony and East Bavaria in preparation for the Austro-Prussian war of 1865, and then in the West Rhinelands in preparation for the 1870 and 1914 campaigns against France. The notion that any other consideration take precedence over military requirements would have struck von Moltke as absurd.